# Redirect file path ">>"

Tags: directory

I have the function:

`function >> file.txt`

this creates the file.txt in my current directory. I have a folder log in the same directory, how would I request file.txt to be created in my log file (a directory higher)? I tried:

`function >> log/file.txt`

and am unsure why this didn't work for me

Comment: That should've worked. Did you get any error messages? Perhaps add `set -x` to the start of the script to debug it.

Comment: WHAT didn't work? Was anything appended to your file? Did the file not exist afterwards? Did the directory not exist before? Please post the error messages, if any or tell us what "didn't work" for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

supposing that you have this structure

- dummy *directory*

  - log *directory*
  - working *directory*

if you are in the working directory you should run

```
function >> ../log/file.txt
```

a quick explanation is:

- the single dot `.` means this level
- the double dots `..` means go up 1 level